# xlwings vs pandas native export with multi index dataframes: how to reconcile?

Tags: excel, pandas, export-to-excel, multi-index, xlwings

I'll start with an image for it explains clearly the problem with exporting multindexes with pandas native export and xlwings

[image]

essentially, I'd like the '`Pandas` native' result [the multiindex properly exported to excel] done with `Xlwings` because I have a bunch of other features that `XlWings` can do and others cannot (no not even if use `ExcelWriter` and the like because I have to clear the sheet and I have a non python thing inserted in the same sheet which would be cleared as well when initialized)

the code used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
import os

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 8), index=index).transpose()
print(s)

# EXPORT

filename = 'format_excel_export.xlsx'
s.to_excel(filename)

outpath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), filename)
os.path.sep = r'/'
wb = xw.Workbook(outpath)

xw.Range('Sheet1', 'A13').value = s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a custom converter that formats it the way that Pandas does, see [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#custom-converter).

However, as of v0.7.2, xlwings doesn't yet natively support bolding fonts, merging cells and cell borders. You can get around this by falling back to pywin32 (on Windows), see [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html).

In essence, your custom converter needs to override the `write_value` method, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/blob/v0.7.2/xlwings/conversion/pandas_conv.py#L55).

It does make sense to build this into the library at some point, so I've opened an issue, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/513).